# when I choose datastore entities it goes to firestore why?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

when I choose datastore entities it goes to firestore why?
how to revert back to original settings in datastore.If I choose native fire store then how cloud change the setting for the same project id?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The old Datastore has been migrated to Firestore in Datastore mode as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/upgrade-to-firestore), additionally, new projects can not access the old Datastore as GCP is pushing to use Firestore which has a better management of consistency as well as other benefits explored over [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#in_datastore_mode).

I hope you find this information useful.